# Google Sheets: Sum if value is round number

Tags: google-sheets, sum, integer, google-sheets-formula, formula

I'm sure there's a pretty simple solution, but I cant' get to it.

I'm trying to sum a list of numbers, but only the values that are round numbers/whole integers.

Eg column A:

```
1
1.5
3
2.4
2
```

sum of the whole numbers

```
1 + 3 + 2 = 6
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose your numbers list begins in A2 and runs downward (i.e., A2:A). You can use this:

```
=SUM(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A=INT(A2:A)))
```

In plain English, this reads as follows: "Sum only those numbers in A2:A where the original value is the same as the integer-only portion of that value."

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=sumproduct((A1:A5)*(A1:A5=int(A1:A5)))
```

this will also work in Excel

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, you can use [SEARCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625) to search for the decimal point:

```
=SUM(A1:A)-SUM(FILTER(A1:A,SEARCH(".",TO_TEXT(A1:A))))
```

[image]

or `=SUM(FILTER(A1:A,NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".",A1:A)))))`

as [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv) mentioned in his comment.

Comment: This is a little bit too tricky IMHO. What if `A5` is `10`? My guess is that OP has very simplified data for us to use.

Comment: @JvdV answer modified, thanks! I upvote yours since all of them are answering the same question. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Thank you for your support. The problem here now is that you are not summing the integers, but the opposite =).

Comment: @JvdV true.. anyway, fixed my answer :)

Comment: Yes that works. Now I don't want to be rude, but a lot cleaner would be `=SUM(FILTER(A1:A;NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".";A1:A)))))` IMO. Anyways. You got my kudos now too, just like the others got them. A small issue up for debate: I don't like the answers that have hardcoded "." in them as much as the others because it's either a decimal point or decimal comma depending on locale.

Comment: @JvdV thanks a lot for your support. Can I use your formula?

Comment: Sorry, I still had the decimal comma in there. Not on purpose but it demonstrates my previous point about hardcoding the decimal point or comma haha

Comment: thanks a lot for both your feedback and support

Comment: Just came up with `=SUM(FILTER(A1:A;ISERROR(SEARCH(".";A1:A))))` =). Enjoy the rest of your day and see you around on SO.

Answer (score 1):

use dot detection:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IF(REGEXMATCH(""&A:A, "\."),,A:A)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Either try `QUERY()`:

```
=SUM(QUERY(A:A,"where A matches '\d+'"))
```

Or `FILTER()`:

```
=SUM(FILTER(A:A,MOD(A:A,1)=0))
```

[image]

**Note:** This 1st option makes use of the possibility to use a regular expression inside the "where" clause of `QUERY()`. Use `=SUM(QUERY(A:A,"where A matches '-?\d+'"))` if you want to account for positive ***and*** negative integers.